# Events with EthersJS are fired multiple times

Tags: reactjs, events, react-hooks, next.js, ethers.js

I have a simple DApp in which I can deposit and withdraw Ethers

[image]

But when executing the following code :

```
useEffect(() => {
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, Contract.abi, provider)
        contract.on("etherDeposited", (account, amount) => {
            toast({
                title: 'Deposit Event',
                description: "Account : " + account + " - amount " + amount,
                status: 'success',
                duration: 5000,
                isClosable: true,
            })
        })
    }, [])
```

We can see that there is some bad rendering there or something like this, I don't understand.

[image]

I've tried to remove the listener by doing

```
useEffect(() => {
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, Contract.abi, provider)
        contract.on("etherDeposited", (account, amount) => {
            toast({
                title: 'Deposit Event',
                description: "Account : " + account + " - amount " + amount,
                status: 'success',
                duration: 5000,
                isClosable: true,
            })
        })
        return () => {
            contract.removeAllListeners();
        };
    }, [])
```

But it doesn't change anything, it's even worse. What did I do wrong there ?

Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

Please check in `main.jsx` or `app.jsx` or `index.jsx` if Strict mode is ON. It renders the useEffect twice and multiple listeners are attached. Remove `<React.StrictMode>` and it should work fine.